# Angular 4 - multiple web applications in a common Web UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Currently, I have 30 web applications (say) and I am trying to include their interfaces in a common web ui. For example, I have a menu on the left with all applications and once I click one, I can see its UI in a middle frame.

The catch here is that these applications have services that can be standardised i.e. when it comes to permissions, a common service can be built which will be called by all applications.

I am looking into doing this without decomposing each application by components. I would like to have minimal work done on the application side.

Has anyone tried to do this before? Do you have any suggestion on an approach? I was thinking of using Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently, I have 30 web applications (say) and I am trying to include
>   their interfaces in a common web ui. For example, I have a menu on the
>   left with all applications and once I click one, I can see its UI in a
>   middle frame.

You can have one module each for each application with its own routing, these modules can be configured for lazy loading.

> The catch here is that these applications have services that can be
>   standardised i.e. when it comes to permissions, a common service can
>   be built which will be called by all applications.

You can provide the common services at root level and provide app specific services in each module.

> I am looking into doing this without decomposing each application by
>   components. I would like to have minimal work done on the application
>   side.

Not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Regarding "You can have one module each for each application with its own routing, these modules can be configured for lazy loading", can this be done even if some applications are built in the old fashioned HTML/CSS/JS style i.e. no in Angular? I am not very familiar with Web development yet...

Comment: I dont think you can mix that way. Atleast its not a standard way so not easy. Angular 4 is mostly done with Typescript and bundled with webpack, this assumes that your complete app including 30+ is done in angular. If you just want a home page showcasing all your apps go ahead and do it in plain javascript/html and link to each app, using angular for **just that** is like killing a fly with sledgehammer.